# Can I combine the .load function with fadeIn in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein

I am using the .load function to load in another page using jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
$('#page1').click(function(){                           
  $("#content").load("page1.html");
});
```

It's working great, but I would like to fade in the new page. Is there anyway I can combine the load and fadeIn function? I attempted it, but it's not working.

Here is my attempt:

```
$('#page1').click(function(){                           
  $("#content").load("page1.html").fadeIn("normal");
});
```

How can I combine the .load and .fadeIn function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The call to `load` will use AJAX and will be run asynchronously. You'll want to fade in right after the call is terminated. You can achieve that by passing a callback to load. Your code will look like this:

```
$('#content').load("page1.html", {}, function() { $(this).fadeIn("normal"); }));
```

See [documentation on jQuery's .load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Hide `#content` before the load, and fade in the entire div when load is complete. I'd guess load acceps a callback function...?

```
$('#content').hide();
$('#content').load('page1.html', function() { $('#content').fadeIn('normal'); });
```

**EDIT** do what miguel said, anyway =)