# Add fade effect to ajax content

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, fade

I have a wordpress site where I have ajax content appearing after my loader when a button is clicked. The code works great but I'd like to **add in the effect where current content will fade out and new content will fade in**, not needing the loader anymore.

```
1.    
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#main-content').on('click', '.jax a, .page-navigation a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'),
                title = jQuery(this).attr('title')
            ;
            jQuery('#main-content').html('<img id="loader" alt="loading" width="43" height="11" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/squares.gif"/ >').load(url+ ' #main-content');
            document.title = title;
            history.pushState({url:url,title:title}, title, url );
          });
        });

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    document.title = event.state.title;
    jQuery('#main-content').html('<img id="loader" alt="loading" width="43" height="11" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/squares.gif"/ >').load(event.state.url+ ' #main-content');
}
```

I've tried multiple variations, such as this below, and it works BUT it doesn't update the address URL along with each post like it does in the first example.

```
2.
jQuery('.jax a, .page-navigation a').live('click', function(event) {
            var link = $(this).attr('href');
            jQuery('#main-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        jQuery('#main-content').load(link+' #main-content', function(){
            jQuery('#main-content').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
            return false;
});
```

Any idea how to add fade to the first example OR add address URL update (History API) with the second example?

Comment: Try taking out `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: that wouldn't add the fade effect.

Comment: I was addressing your "address bar url seems to not update" comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution for you, but maybe this answer to someone elses question can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789347/4867333

> The call to `load` will use AJAX and will be run asynchronously. You'll want to fade in right after the call is terminated. You can achieve that by passing a callback to load. Your code will look like this:
>
> `$('#content').load("page1.html", {}, function() { $(this).fadeIn("normal"); }));`
>
> See [documentation on jQuery's .load()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback) for more information.

---

Or this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337696/4867333

He was able to achieve the fadeOut, fadeIn by applying the effect to the wrapper div.

---

You could try the following:

```
jQuery('.jax a, .page-navigation a').live('click', function(event) {
        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href'),
            title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
        jQuery('#main-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    jQuery('#main-content').load(url+' #main-content', function(){
        jQuery('#main-content').fadeIn('slow');
        document.title = title;
        history.pushState({url:url,title:title}, title, url );
    });
});
        return false;
});
```

Comment: the "history.pushState" method does that. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries

I had a go at your code, see my edited answer above. I'm definitely not sure, so sorry if it doesn't.